# Pandas Dataframe split columns list simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'period':[
                  [{'periods': [{'From': '19', 'To': '21'}]}, {'periods': [{'From': '13', 'To': '30'}]}, {'periods': [{'From': '02', 'To': '26'}]}],  
                  [{'periods': [{'From': '21', 'To': '26'}]}, {'periods': [{'From': '22', 'To': '27'}]}, {'periods': [{'From': '05', 'To': '07'}]}]
                 ], 
        'Age':[
                  ['9820', '5480', '8535'], 
                  ['1524', '6555', '4555']
              ], 
        'Address':[
                    '2', 
                    '3'
                   ]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would like to transform my dataset in this way:

```
data = {'Name':[
{'periods': [{'From': '19', 'To': '21'}]}, 
{'periods': [{'From': '13', 'To': '30'}]}, 
{'periods': [{'From': '02', 'To': '26'}]}
,  
{'periods': [{'From': '21', 'To': '26'}]}, 
{'periods': [{'From': '22', 'To': '27'}]}, 
{'periods': [{'From': '05', 'To': '07'}]}
], 
        'Age':['9820', '5480', '8535','1524', '6555', '4555'], 
        'Address':['2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I am struggling to find a way to do `explode()` on two columns simultaneously so that the first element of the list in the column period belongs to the same row of the first element of the list in the column Age.

period list and age list are always of equal size.

I tried doing this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
uid = df.set_index('index')['period'].explode().reset_index()
df = uid.join(df['Age'].explode())
```

but it does not show the `Address` column anymore

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` + `explode`:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
                                      period   Age Address
0  {'periods': [{'From': '19', 'To': '21'}]}  9820       2
1  {'periods': [{'From': '13', 'To': '30'}]}  5480       2
2  {'periods': [{'From': '02', 'To': '26'}]}  8535       2
3  {'periods': [{'From': '21', 'To': '26'}]}  1524       3
4  {'periods': [{'From': '22', 'To': '27'}]}  6555       3
5  {'periods': [{'From': '05', 'To': '07'}]}  4555       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try explode them manually:

```
names = df.period.explode()
ages = df.Age.explode()

pd.DataFrame({'Name':names, 'Age':ages, 'Address':df.Address.reindex(ages.index)})
```

Output:

```
                                        Name   Age Address
0  {'periods': [{'From': '19', 'To': '21'}]}  9820       2
0  {'periods': [{'From': '13', 'To': '30'}]}  5480       2
0  {'periods': [{'From': '02', 'To': '26'}]}  8535       2
1  {'periods': [{'From': '21', 'To': '26'}]}  1524       3
1  {'periods': [{'From': '22', 'To': '27'}]}  6555       3
1  {'periods': [{'From': '05', 'To': '07'}]}  4555       3
```